# xp_cmdshell raising error when running script on a remote server by server authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Sqlcmd: Error: Error occurred while opening or operating on file C:\ewApps\Source\MyIssueApp\Scripts\DBScripts\issueUpdateSchemaVersion.sql (Reason: The system cannot find the path specified).

here is my sql script-

```
    Declare @ScriptVersion ='1.1'
Declare @TargetScriptVersionNo = '1.1'
Declare @DBServerName VARCHAR(50)= 'remote-a'
Declare @DBName VARCHAR(50)='mydb'
Declare @FilePath NVARCHAR(MAX)= 'C:\ewApps\Source\MyIssueApp\Scripts\DBScripts\issueUpdateSchemaVersion.sql'
DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(10) = 'sa'
DECLARE @Password VARCHAR(20) = 'sql1k9@abcd'
DECLARE @Command =''

set @Command = ' sqlcmd -S ' + @DBServerName + ' -U ' + @UserName + ' -P '+ @Password + ' -d ' + @DBName + ' -i "'+ @FilePathForAllScript + '" -v SubScriptVersion=''' + @VersionNumber + ''''

EXEC xp_cmdshell @Command
```

the generated string @command is -

sqlcmd -S ewp-dev14 -U sa -P sql2k8@dev14 -d a -i "C:\ewApps\Source\MyIssueApp\Scripts\DBScripts\issueUpdateSchemaVersion.sql" -v SubScriptVersion='1.1'

and also

sqlcmd -S ewp-dev14 -U sa -P sql2k8@dev14 -d a -i C:\ewApps\Source\MyIssueApp\Scripts\DBScripts\issueUpdateSchemaVersion.sql -v SubScriptVersion='1.1'

i think this is a long path related issue, but when i pass a small path, it works like c:\ewapps\issueUpdateSchemaVersion.sql, but i cant use small path , the path mentioned above is mandatory..

i dont have any space in my path still i have tried it by applying both "" (double codes) and without double codes but its not working, and showing following error-

Sqlcmd: Error: Error occurred while opening or operating on file C:\ewApps\Source\MyIssueApp\Scripts\DBScripts\issueUpdateSchemaVersion.sql (Reason: The system cannot find the path specified).

all the above parameters are coming from a batch file.

Note- My this server is at TFS, can it be an issue ?? please help...

Comment: Please remove the SA password before posting...

Comment: Is the file located on the same server as the SQL Server?

Comment: thanx dean for ur reply... yes the file is located at the same server. Means at my local machine i have all sql files and at that Remote server there is only sql server.

Comment: what happens when you execute the command directly from cmd.exe?

Comment: let me explain the whole scenario- First of all a batch file executes 2 sql files directly , and both executes properly on remote server. than 3rd sql file which executes five more sql files one by one. so when control comes to execute these five file, which are called inside a sql file, it raises sqlcmd error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Network path:

```
\\\Server\yourfolder\yourfile.csv,
```

You have to share your folder `yourfolder`